# importing txt into R

Tags: r, import, ftp

I am trying to read an ftp file from the internet ("ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/pub/settle/stlint") into R, using the following command:
aaa<-read.table("ftp://ftp.cmegroup.vom/pub/settle/stlint", sep="\t", skip=2, header=FALSE)

the result shows the 8th, 51st, 65th, 71st, 72nd, 73rd, 74th, etc etc rows of the resulting dataset as including add-on rows appended at the end.  Basically instead of returning 
{row8}
{row9}
etc 
{row162}
{row163}

It returns (adding in the quotes around the \n)
{row8'\n'row9'\n'etc...etc...'\n'row162}
{row163}

If it seems like i'm picking arbitrary numbers then run the code above, take a look at the actual ftp file on the internet (as of mid-day feb18) and you'll see i'm not, it really adding 155x rows onto the end of the 8th row.  So what i'm looking for is simply I'm looking for a way to read it in without the random appending of rows.  Thanks, and apologize in advance i'm new to R and was not able to find this fix after a while of searching.

Comment: Does not seem to have tabs so I'm guessing that read.table is only seeing one value per line. Appears to be a fixed width format but with the added complication of having blocks of data signified by non-date values at the leftmost column.

Comment: You also get a warning about "EOF within quoted string" and there are single quote-marks that are clearly not string delimiters so you should be setting `quote=""` if your persist in using `read.table`. (I don't really think `read.table` is appropriate.)

Comment: ok- thanks, what function would you suggest to read this in?    (also, if it matters, i changed from sep="\t" to fill=TRUE, which seems to take care of the appending-rows problem, but now pushes all data in each row to the left.  Again, more than open to trying another method for importing data, just don't know any other options).

Comment: Because of the various sections within that text file I would think you would need to use `readLines` and then break into sections before constructing dataframes with the sections using `read.table(text=. , ...)`.